# Flutter Scroll To Index tem In ListView Error

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello friends i am beginner in flutter and my problem is that when my listview sacreen is load i want jump to specific item in list view  i am using scrollable_positioned_list  package problem is that when sacreen is loaded   i am getting this error

Null check operator used on a null value
here is my code

```
    import 'dart:math';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
    import 'package:scrollable_positioned_list/scrollable_positioned_list.dart';
    
    
    import 'Dbhelper.dart';
    
    
    class Allverse extends StatefulWidget {
      late int booknumber;
      late int chapternumber;
    
    
      @override
      _AllverseState createState() => _AllverseState();
    
      Allverse(this.booknumber, this.chapternumber);
    }
    
    class _AllverseState extends State<Allverse> {
      final ItemScrollController itemScrollController = ItemScrollController();
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        // TODO: implement initState
        super.initState();
    //this method load listview all item   
 getallverse();
    
       //here when item load i want jump to postion 10 in item  
 itemScrollController.jumpTo(index: 10);
      }
    
      List<Map<String, dynamic>> allverse = [];
    
      void getallverse() async {
        final data = await Dbhelper.fetchallverse(widget.booknumber, widget.chapternumber);
        setState(() {
    
          allverse= data;
        });
    
      }
    
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('All verse'),
    
          ),
          body:SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              children: [
              Container(
               height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                  child: ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
                    itemCount: allverse.length,
                    itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
    
                    itemBuilder:(context,index){
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap:(){
                          print(index);
    
                        },
                        child: Card(
                          child: ListTile(
                            leading: CircleAvatar(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                              //backgroundColor:Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)] ,
                              radius: 12,
                              child: Text(allverse[index]['v'].toString(),style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  fontSize:12
                              ),),
                            ),
                            title: Column(
                              children: [
                                Text(allverse[index]['t'].toString(),
                                    style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                      fontSize: 16,
    
                                    )
    
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.favorite_border,
                                      color: Colors.red[500],
                                    ),
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.speaker,
                                      color: Colors.red[500],
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                )
                              ],
    
                            ),
    
                            trailing: Icon(
                              Icons.share,
                              color: Colors.red,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
    
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
    
            ),
          )
    
    
        );
      }
    }

flutter: Opening existing database
flutter: Opening existing database

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _CastError was thrown building Builder:
Null check operator used on a null value

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  MaterialApp MaterialApp:file:///Users/apple/Documents/bibleapp/lib/main.dart:14:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ItemScrollController.jumpTo (package:scrollable_positioned_list/src/scrollable_positioned_list.dart:206:25)
#1      _AllverseState.initState (package:bibleapp/Allverse.dart:30:26)
#2      StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4728:57)
#3      ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4561:5)
...     Normal element mounting (24 frames)
#27     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3631:14)
#28     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6261:36)
#29     MultiChildRenderObjectElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6272:32)
...     Normal element mounting (173 frames)
#202    Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3631:14)
#203    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6261:36)
#204    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3383:18)
#205    RenderObjectElement.updateChildren (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5684:32)
#206    MultiChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6284:17)
#207    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3370:15)
#208    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4613:16)
#209    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4763:11)
#210    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4311:5)
#211    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4795:5)
#212    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3370:15)
#213    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4613:16)
#214    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4311:5)
#215    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4943:5)
#216    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3370:15)
#217    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4613:16)
#218    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4311:5)
#219    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4943:5)
#220    _InheritedNotifierElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/inherited_notifier.dart:111:11)
#221    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3370:15)
#222    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6130:14)
#223    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3370:15)
#224    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4613:16)
#225    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4763:11)
#226    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4311:5)
#227    StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4795:5)
#228    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3370:15)
#229    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6130:14)
#230    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3370:15)
#231    SingleChildRenderObjectElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:6130:14)
#232    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3370:15)
#233    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4613:16)
#234    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4311:5)
#235    ProxyElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4943:5)
#236    Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3370:15)
#237    ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4613:16)
#238    StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4763:11)
#239    Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4311:5)
#240    BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2578:33)
#241    WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:882:21)
#242    RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:363:5)
#243    SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1145:15)
#244    SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1082:9)
#245    SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:996:5)
#249    _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:150:10)
#250    PlatformDispatcher._drawFrame (dart:ui/platform_dispatcher.dart:270:5)
#251    _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:114:31)
(elided 3 frames from dart:async)
====================================================================================================
```

Comment: If you make it return 'Future<void>` you can use `.then` on `getallverse` method, and execute `jumpTo` after it. Like: `getallverse().then(()=>itemScrollController.jumpTo(index: 10))`

Answer (score 0):

I think you did not give a value to one of these two variables

late int booknumber;
late int chapternumber;

check the widget you are calling Allverse() from it

Comment: value is successfully loaded problem is that listview and jumpto method loaded together in intatstat{} so listview takes some time to load but at same time jumto(10) method is also excuted at the same time thats why i am getting this error so i need fixed this issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve this by putting the controller.jump into Future.delay after 1 to 2 minute or what you put the time . when your list has been updated then your controller.jump run and it will not give you null

```
import 'dart:math';
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
        import 'package:google_fonts/google_fonts.dart';
        import 'package:scrollable_positioned_list/scrollable_positioned_list.dart';
        
        
        import 'Dbhelper.dart';
        
        
        class Allverse extends StatefulWidget {
          late int booknumber;
          late int chapternumber;
        
        
          @override
          _AllverseState createState() => _AllverseState();
        
          Allverse(this.booknumber, this.chapternumber);
        }
        
        class _AllverseState extends State<Allverse> {
          final ItemScrollController itemScrollController = ItemScrollController();
        
          @override
          void initState() {
            // TODO: implement initState
            super.initState();
        //this method load listview all item   
     getallverse();

    });
        
    
          }
        
          List<Map<String, dynamic>> allverse = [];
        
          void getallverse() async {
            final data = await Dbhelper.fetchallverse(widget.booknumber, widget.chapternumber);
            setState(() {
        
              allverse= data;
            });
        
          }
        
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text('All verse'),
        
              ),
              body:SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                  Container(
                   height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                      child: ScrollablePositionedList.builder(
                        itemCount: allverse.length,
                        itemScrollController: itemScrollController,
        
                            itemBuilder:(context,index){
                           if(allverse.length == index){
                                 itemScrollController.jumpTo(index: 10);
                            }
                          return GestureDetector(
                            onTap:(){
                              print(index);
        
                            },
                            child: Card(
                              child: ListTile(
                                leading: CircleAvatar(
                                  backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                                  //backgroundColor:Colors.primaries[Random().nextInt(Colors.primaries.length)] ,
                                  radius: 12,
                                  child: Text(allverse[index]['v'].toString(),style: TextStyle(
                                      color: Colors.white,
                                      fontSize:12
                                  ),),
                                ),
                                title: Column(
                                  children: [
                                    Text(allverse[index]['t'].toString(),
                                        style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                          fontSize: 16,
        
                                        )
        
                                    ),
                                    Row(
                                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                      children: [
                                        Icon(
                                          Icons.favorite_border,
                                          color: Colors.red[500],
                                        ),
                                        Icon(
                                          Icons.speaker,
                                          color: Colors.red[500],
                                        ),
                                      ],
                                    )
                                  ],
        
                                ),
        
                                trailing: Icon(
                                  Icons.share,
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
        
                        },
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
        
                ),
              )
        
        
            );
          }
        }
```

if my answer will help you please mark my answer as accepted

Comment: hello thanks its working if you have another method please also tell me or if have any other solution where i check lisview item completely build then i jump to postion becaue i want when sacreen is loaded

Comment: I update my aswer have a look

Comment: this is  not working

Comment: you always want to jump on 10..?

Comment: no it do nothing

Comment: I'm asking. you just want to jump on 10..??

Comment: no always jump to 10 i have two sacreen  first one is index numbers for example 1 , 2,3,4,5 when user click on  index 5  from first sacreen it goes to  second sacreen select item from list view item 5  this my task but you dont care about it you just tell when sacreen is loaded user will jump to any index item from list view  for example if i want jump to item 5 when sacreen is loaded listview item jump to 5 index

Comment: I recommend you my last answer